complex 3-dimensional algebra
I want to find matrices that will fit the given structural equations to the Lie algebra:
$$ [e_1,e_2]=2e_2, [e_1,e_3]=-e_3,   [e_2,e_3]=0 $$
At first, I thought it was similar to Poincaré algebra. But, I have not succeeded in linear transformations to the commutators of such an algebra.
Now I have only one idea. It is to write equations on matrix elements.  But it seems to me that this method is not quite rational.
Perhaps someone knows what this algebra is ? Thanks in advance for the reply.

I enclosed your expression in dollar signs to allow MathJax to render it. Please check that it properly represents your intention, thanks!

We know exactly which Lie algebra this is. Note that the commutator subalgebra is $2$-dimensional. So it must be a solvable Lie algebra. You can find a full classification of such algebras ($3$-dimensional with $2$-dimensional commutator) here, on page $29$.

A faithful representation $\rho\colon L\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_3(\Bbb C)$ is given as follows:
$$
\rho(e_1)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\cr  0 & 2 & 0\cr  0 & 0 & -1\cr  \end{pmatrix},\quad \rho(e_2)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\cr  -2 & 0 & 0\cr  0 & 0 & 0\cr  \end{pmatrix}, \quad \rho(e_3)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\cr  0 & 0 & 0\cr  1 & 0 & 0\cr  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
In fact, this is the adjoint representation. The Lie algebra $L$ satisfies $\dim(L)=3, \dim [L,L]=2$, and hence is a solvable Lie algebra.
The complexification of the Lie algebra of the Poincaré group is the Poincaré Lie algebra $\mathfrak{p}(3, 1)$, which is isomorphic to $$(\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)\times \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C))\ltimes (\Bbb C^2\otimes \Bbb C^2).$$
It is certainly not $3$-dimensional over $\Bbb C$.

Thank you! And how did you get this result? is it a straight forward computation and solving the equation on matrices ? Or you first said that there is a Jordan form for e_1 and then solved the system of equations? I was trying be myself but was not successful.

No, it is just the matrix for the linear map given by the Lie bracket. So by $[e_1,e_2]=ad(e_1)(e_2)$ the matrix $ad(e_1)$ must have the second column vector $(0,2,0)$, because $[e_1,e_2]=2e_2$, so this is easy. It gives a faithful matrix representation, since $\ker(ad)=Z(L)=0$.
